# mysql replace into with if statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "supported_languages" looks like that:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
language_ref   |   language _name   |   language_active   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
en             |    English         |        Y            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
es             |    Espanol         |        Y            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
fr             |    Francias        |        Y            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
he             |    hebrew          |       NULL          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to create a query that will set only the english language to be active **ONLY if the 3 languages - en,es,fr are active (Y) and "he" language is null** (same as table provided). only in that case - change everything to be N under "language_active" and keep english to be the only language that active.

any help?

thanks!

Comment: please share you expected output as per your logic you defined. This will help community to understand more precisely and people can help you better.

Comment: Is there a fourth not shown column, e.g. `user`?  You are asking for an update of an entire table and it seems weird.

Comment: I know it's a little weird but it's a special case.

Comment: if I get the same value as described here in the table then I want this table to be changed and show "en" as the only language that active.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put something like this into an update trigger.

```
if exists (select * from supported_languages where language_ref = 'en' and language_active = 'Y')
    and exists (select * from supported_languages where language_ref = 'es' and language_active = 'Y')
    and exists (select * from supported_languages where language_ref = 'fr' and language_active = 'Y')
    and exists (select * from supported_languages where language_ref = 'he' and language_active = 'N')
    update supported_languages set language_active = 'N' 
where language_ref = 'es' or language_ref = 'fr'
```

Comment: thanks! yes thats what I need but "if exists" does not work for me. I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: Then you can remove the exists keyword and append "= 0". For example, if (Select * from supported_language where xxx) = 0